# How to convert Kotlin project to Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile after the project completion?

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, native, kotlin-multiplatform

I have built a code in Android Studio with Kotlin. I initially haven't set it up as a Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile project and I would like to bring it now also on iOS. Is there a way to "convert" it to a Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile at this stage? Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4):

This is a multi-step process:

1. You'll need to adapt your build configuration - change `build.gradle.kts` to a KMM setup. Examples you can find at [PeopleInSpace](https://github.com/joreilly/PeopleInSpace/blob/main/common/build.gradle.kts) and [KaMPKit](https://github.com/touchlab/KaMPKit/blob/main/shared/build.gradle.kts) repos
2. You have to make your Android code platform agnostic in order to share pieces with iOS

The changes you need to make depends on how many Android dependencies you have, how much platform-specific code you wrote and how much you want to share with iOS.

I wouldn't underestimate how big of a refactor this might need, as there are loads of platform-specific things that as an Android devs can overlook (JUnit, File, Dates are just a few examples, where we commonly used JVM libs)

I'd recommend starting small, creating a `shared` module with a KMM configuration, then step-by-step moving things to `shared`

Reach out if you have more questions

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for your quick and detailed answer. I've been going through some of the steps that I should cover and since my Kotlin code is loaded with Android dependencies I was thinking if maybe the quickest solution could be to redo the app from scratch with Swift on Xcode? Does it sound like a crazy idea in your opinion? I'd still need to learn how to code in Swift by the way, but I believe it shouldn't be that tough.

Comment: @Drago, I think it depends. If you want to get iOS done quick, I'd be inclined to say yes, it might be faster coding it out in Swift.
If you plan on making long-lived apps with reduced maintainability costs sharing logic with KMM would be a good idea

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this detailed video that explains this process https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X6ckI1JWjqo

You would need to switch using Kotlin native libraries for common shared code, so depending on that, you might have more or less work to do.

On top of that, you would need to use strategies around dependency injection, common view model layer etc.